# How to dynamically add values from a csv into an array

Tags: python, csv

I want to read row values from a csv and insert them into an array or any data structure that would work well for this case. So I read my row time stamp values and insert into data structure, I then read my next time stamp and since they both have the same price the only thing that needs to be updated is the PriceQuanity in the new dataframe. What data structure would work best for this method, and how to go about updating data structure dynamically?

Data in my csv

| Time | Price | PriceQ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .01 | 23 | 20 |
| .02 | 23 | 18 |

Data in my new DataFrame

| Price | PriceQ |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 38 |

Comment: Please add your existing code to show how you are trying to do it, and the current output.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you really use array? How do you add items to array? Maybe you use dictionary. Better show minimal working code which we could run. And show example data - maybe problem is in data.

Comment: I would start by writing my needs in pseudocode. Like "Open CSV from start. Create array. Read next line, if seen before, skip this, else add. " etc etc.  Once you know WHAT you want, it's simple to google / watch a tutorial about HOW you do it. No matter the language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSV looks like:

```
Time,Price,PriceQ
.01,23,20
.02,23,18
```

I would suggest you use a `defaultdict` dictionary to store your prices. This allows you to easily update each key. For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

data = defaultdict(int)

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    
    for tm, price, priceq in csv_input:
        data[price] += int(priceq)

for price, priceq in data.items():
    print(price, priceq)
```